# What is the internal implementation of Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Apple");
list.add("Cherry");
list.add("Peach");

List<String> collect = list.stream()
        .peek(x -> System.out.println(x))
        .filter(x -> x.length()>4)
        .peek(x -> System.out.println(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will print:

```
Apple
Apple
Cherry
Cherry
Peach
Peach
```

So my conclusion is :

The 1st input of the stream will be processed till the end of the stream.
Only then the 2nd input of the stream will be processed and again till the end of the stream.

That is totally different to normal method calls. Normally you would expect ALL inputs will be processed at one method call . If you call peek() I expected I will see

```
Apple
Cherry
Peach
```

but that is not the case.

So implementation of stream() would be it has a for loop inside and successively calls the following chain of methods with only a single input.

Comment: pull vs push approach. nothing weird here

Comment: `Stream`s operate lazy. Furthermore, no particular order of processing is guaranteed.

Comment: The code is freely available in many places so you can just open it and look at exactly how it was done.

Comment: Heavily simplified: `peek` and `filter` don't actually process the items which are to be streamed. Instead, they define pieces of a pipeline. Only `collect` (and other *terminal operations*) trigger the 'built' pipeline to actually run.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the described manner of [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)). See (emphasis mine):

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element **as elements are consumed from the resulting stream**.

So the peek action (or actions in your case), that you have registered will be performed when the elements are consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are built specifically to be lazily evaluated. In other words: streams try to do as few operations necessary to get to the desired result of the terminal operation (and if you don't do any terminal operations, then a stream will usually not do anything at all).

This is explicitly [documented in the JavaDoc of `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed.

Terminal operations are those that contain the text "This is a terminal operation".